# Tough integration : $e^{ik\cos\theta}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

Is there a way to get a hint about these kind of integrations?

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{ik\cos\theta}d\theta$$ or $$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{k\cos\theta}d\theta$$

Thanks in advance

**Edit :** I tried that. A simple change of variable $\cos{\theta}= x$: $$\int_0^{\pi}e^{k\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^{kx}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\int_{-1}^{1}\arcsin'(x)e^{kx}dx \\ =[\arcsin(x)e^{kx}]^{1}_{-1}-k\int_{-1}^{1}\arcsin(x)e^{kx}dx \\ =[\arcsin(x)e^{kx}]^{1}_{-1}-[k(\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\arcsin(x))e^{kx}]^{1}_{-1}+k^2 \int_{-1}^{1}(\sqrt{1-x^2}+x\arcsin(x))e^{kx}dx$$

It looks right but it doesn't look like it's leading anywhere

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel's_integrals) may be useful

Comment: What do you know about integration? What have you tried?

Comment: By $$\int_{[0,2\pi]}$$ do you mean $$\int_0^{2\pi}$$? Also, what is $k$ here?

Comment: @JohnDoe Thx it's indeed useful !                                                                                    And k is a constant.

Comment: @clathratus $\int_{A}$ is usually used for Lebesgue integral on the set $A$.

Comment: @Botond then why isn't the question tagged [Lebesgue-theory]?

Comment: @clathratus I don't know. As you can see, the post wasn't made by me. Would it be necessary?

Comment: @clathratus as u probably noticed, I rewrote it.

Comment: @J.A Thank you for the clarification (+1).